# ESP8266 Huzzah error: "Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header"

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/using-arduino-ide) but when I get to the step...

"Once the ESP board is in bootload mode, upload the sketch via the IDE"

..I get the following error in Arduino IDE:

```
File "[path]/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 468, in connect
    raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: it is not in bootload mode